# How can I set up moment.js in the vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, vue-component, vuetify.js

I using vuetify : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/
I want to use moment.js. So I read this reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

I had run `npm install vue-moment`

I'm still confused to put this script `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));`

In the vuetify, there exist two file : main.js and index.js

main.js like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/index'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

index.js like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import dataStore from './modules/data-store';
import createLogger from "vuex/dist/logger";
Vue.use(Vuex);
const debug = process.env.VUE_APP_DEBUG !== "production";
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    dataStore
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
});
```

where do i put `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));`?

I try to put it in the main.js, but if i call my vue component, there exist error : `ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let a = moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
    console.log(a)
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: if you just want to use `moment` in your vue component you could try doing `import moment from 'moment` or `const moment  = require('moment')` inside the script tag above `export default`

Comment: @TJ Weems It works. Thanks. But how do i make it globally? so there's no need to put it on every component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this at the bottom of the `vue-moment` npm page

```
vue-moment attaches the momentjs instance to your Vue app as 
this.$moment.

This allows you to call the static methods momentjs provides.
```

So you should be able to use your original configuration of `vue-moment` and do this in your `mounted()` method

```
 mounted() {
    let a = this.$moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
    console.log(a)
 }
```

notice `this.$moment`

And for the set up of `vue-moment` you should place this in your main.js file

`main.js`

```
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
```

=========================================================================

**GLOBAL**

If you want to use `moment` with Vue globally you can create an [Instance Proprety](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html)

`main.js`

```
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.prototype.moment = moment
```

In your component you then call `this.moment` in your methods or computed properties. In your `mounted` section it would look like this

```
 mounted() {
   let a = this.moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
   console.log(a)
 }
```

**COMPONENT**

If you just want to use `moment` in a component you can include directly like this

```
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
  mounted(){
    let a = moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
    console.log(a)
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: without installing `npm install vue-moment`, your script works. how the script works without installing moment

Comment: Okay thanks. But can you update your answer using the second way, namely vue moment. so later in your answer there are several ways

Comment: @SuccessMan I got it changed for you.

Comment: I mean this:https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment. So it using vue-moment. Maybe it will add `import VueMoment from 'vue-moment'`

Comment: No just place `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))` in your main.js file.

Comment: I had add `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))` in my main.js file, but it does not works

Comment: @SuccessMan, I just tried in one of my projects and it works fine. Perhaps try reinstalling `vue-moment`.

Comment: You just add `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))` in main.js? and it works globally? can be accessed in all components

Comment: @SuccessMan, yes sir.

Comment: Okay. I will try it. Thanks a lot

Comment: There exist error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined`